# alignment changing when resizing the window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Am trying this main wrapper style in my page. Initially it's ok, but because of `min-width` of left-pane my right-pane in going down when I resize my window. Can anybody please help how to keep the right-pane adjustable when resize. But we should not change the `min-width`.

```
<body >
<div class="master-container">

    <div class="left-panel"></div>
    <div class="right-panel"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

```
.left-panel{
    float: left;
    width: 18%;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 256px;
    border: 1px solid #294777;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}       
.right-panel {
    float: left;
    width: 82%;
    min-width: 700px !important;
    max-height: 764px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid #294777;
    height: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty hard to suggest as I don't know your aims in terms of responsivness and content in those divs.

Maybe this could be a start for you :

**updated** according to comments.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c9HA2/29/)**
HTML:

```
<div class="master-container">
    <div class="left-panel"></div>
    <div class="right-panel">
        <div class="in"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.master-container{
    min-width:984px;
}
.left-panel {
    float: left;
    width: 26%;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 256px;
    background:green;
}
.right-panel {
    width:72%;
    min-width:728px;
    max-height: 764px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
.in{
    width:100%;
    min-width:728px;
    height: 200px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Comment: UPDATED updated the css and the fiddle I think it is what you need now. Min-width is kept.

Comment: i should set some initial width to my right panel know.if i do like this my right panel contents are mis-aligning each other

Comment: can you post the code with the content so I can suggest something else pls? other qusetion : do you need the borders?

Comment: ya i have one more div inside the right-panel..that div has 728px width..that is the problem..I aligned content for that inner div..and i  am not suppose to  change the 728 px div...and i don want border and all.to be more clear i posted.

Comment: could you post your original code in a fiddle, it would be more clear(http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I done small modification in fiddle.I should remove float left from right panel..that is the major point in that. please look on it..i got an idea from your suggestions..thanks a lot http://jsfiddle.net/c9HA2/30/